# Get product description with metafield in shopify

Tags: shopify, product, liquid

I am trying to get product description with liquid but it always render something else, I wjust want know how I can fetch product description with the help of liquid code
I am using following code
{{ product.metafields.custom.us_product.value.description }}

tried
{{ product.metafields.custom.us_product.value.description }}

expecting solution in liquid

Comment: That should work. Double check that `us_product` contains a product

Comment: It works when I add truncate filter

Answer (score 2):

There should not be `.value` in  `product.metafields.custom.us_product.value.description`

`us_product` is the key

`product.metafields.custom.us_product` is the value

Plus, from your line, what is `.description`?  You are basically getting the "description" of a string stored in metafield.  `.description` does not exist.

Below is how you get a product with metafields.  The product handle is stored in the metafields.

put the name in bracket to include space and special characters.

There is a 64 character limit on metafield key;

```
{% assign usProductHandle = product.metafields.custom["us_product"]%}
{% assign usProductDescription = all_products[productHandle].description %}

{{usProductDescription}}
```